# T4 template shadow copy does not work

Tags: visual-studio-2012, t4

I'm using VS2012 and T4 templates and [assemblies are supposed to be shadow copied](http://www.olegsych.com/2012/12/t4-toolbox-for-visual-studio-2012/), meaning that you can reference an assembly in a template and then recompile that assembly.  But this simply doesn't work for me.  When I try it, when I try to rebuild the assembly, I get errors like:

```
Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\xxx.dll" to "..\bin\xxx.dll". 
The process cannot access the file '..\bin\xxx.dll' because it is being used by another process.
```

The only way around it is to restart Visual Studio, and this is so tedious that I'm ready to abandon T4 entirely.  What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I think this was added in VS2012 SP1. Which version are you using?

Comment: My mistake that, was added in VS2010 SP1. VS2012 should support it oob. Do you have a sample which reproes it?

Comment: @FuleSnabel: *Any* assembly directive that references any executable does this.  VS locks the file and if I try to recompile it, it fails because the file isn't writable.

Answer (score 0):

*So this isn't really an answer yet but hopefully we get there*

Test ran the following in VS2013 (I realize you run VS2012)

```
<#@ assembly name = "$(SolutionDir)\TestProj\bin\Debug\TestProj.dll"#>
<#@ import namespace = "TestProj"#>

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class <#=Testing.Name#>
    {

    }
}
```

The TestProj contains the Testing class

```
namespace TestProj
{
    public static class Testing
    {
        public static string Name
        {
            get { return "Tester" ;}
        }
    }
}
```

This did work very well in VS2013 and as far as I remember this worked in VS2012 as well.I will try to install VS2012 on one of my machines but do you mind testing this simple sample on your installation to validate it's not something in your solution that holds the dll?

In case you are interested in the project file you can find it here:
https://github.com/mrange/CodeStack/tree/master/q21118821

Comment: I'll give this a try when I have some time and report back.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I work around similar issue.  T4 design time template is processed in different App domain under the same process of visual studio. When rebuild the solution Visual Studio tries to replace the referenced DLL, and it cannot replace it because it is still in use.

I work around this issue by deleting the AppDomain in which T4 template is processed. See [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495329.aspx)